# hibernate firebird - creating new table

Tags: hibernate, firebird, jaybird

I'm working in a new project that I need to migrate a system Delphi + Firebird and I'm going to use Java 7 + JSF 2 + JPA (Hibernate) + Firebird. I configured the project and it's working, but I have a problem, The Hibernate is creating a new table for each `@entity` that I have in the project. For example I have a table `XXX` and hibernate is going to create a table `HT_XXX` with attributes primary key of table `XXX` and `HIB_SESS_ID`.

Is there any special properties that I tell the hibernate stops to create this new table?

Answer (score 2):

The tables prefixed with `HT_` are temporary tables that Hibernate uses for certain bulk operations. You can't prevent Hibernate from creating them AFAIK.

See:

- https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1004781
- http://thamayanthiguhan.blogspot.nl/2011/03/ht-tables-in-hibernate.html

Comment: why does the hibernate create only for Firebird DB? I work with another DB as MySql, PostGres and Oracle and it doesn't create this temporary tables. thanks.

Comment: @AlissonVieira I don't use Hibernate, but as far as I can tell from the documentation, Hibernate also creates them for other database. The problem may be that the Hibernate dialect for Firebird doesn't know about global temporary tables, so it creates them as normal tables instead.

Comment: I understand, I made a test with eclipseLink and it didn't create this temporary table. Do you know if i can disable this option or tell for hibernate create this table as Global?

Comment: EclipseLink is not the same as Hibernate, so naturally it does different things. I don't know Hibernate well enough, but you'd probably need to create an alternate dialect that supports the creation of global temporary tables.

Comment: you're sure, I needed to create class that extends FirebirdDialetec and worked. I used this link, http://babickababa.blogspot.com.br/2011/01/running-hibernate-and-jpa-with-firebird.html Thanks Mark Rotteveel

Comment: Good to hear. That blog contained an interesting comment on problems with resultsets that I'll need to investigate (I maintain Jaybird). Time that I get more familiar with Hibernate ;)